# What height/ distance from ceiling or above surfaces would be good for uplighting/ scone wall lamp?

Tags: lighting, light-fixture, recessed-lighting

So in Houston, I had an Uplighting Floor lamp like this with a 3 way/ mode 110 W bulb. The lighting was not as jarring as a office CFL tube but perfectly bright for all that I needed to do in my room/ my desk.

[image: fl 1]
[image: fl 2]

Fast forward to here (Asia), there's no space for a floor lamp so to replicate the above I started looking for same or similar lighting but couldn't find conical uplight wall lamps.

The next best thing was this semi spherical / circular up lighting in subtle frosted look.

[image: l1]
[image: l 2]
3rd too busy & don't like color 
[image: wl3]

**Question:**

What kind of height positioning / distance range would be good for them? Man/ max. And why?

Room height; 10 ft Ceiling if I remember correctly.

5 inch x 1 ft false ceiling / PoP on Alum framing on all 4 sides of room, is to act as space for concealed wiring.
[image: r1]

Answer (score 1):

You're first consideration should be glare. Typically we try and set the best lighting above,slightly behind and on the right hand side of the head. This gives best lighting for reading or using a computer screen (for a right hander anyway). I have never seen a height requirement for a sconce from a reference source like the AIA. other than keep it away from head banging or a shoulder breaker. A fire egress would keep it above 7'4". In this case its not an egress so I would say use your best discretion.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I would totally use that falsing area for **cove lighting**.

[image]

*This is rotating RGB lighting, you wouldn't use that,  just white.*

I would get rid of the 5" vertical drywall and have the horizontal drywall come out more than 12" to hide the vertical struts (or push them back).

On the topside of the horizontal surfaces, about 2" inward, I'd run LED strips.  The light would bounce off the (real) ceiling and illuminate the room *very* evenly.  Looks super pro. And no ugly fixtures.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion but that's not an option and way off from what I had asked (and then fell badly ill)